# Finding Wireless Card Chipset

Tags: drivers, intel-wireless, aircrack-ng

I have been trying to install Aircrack-ng, but, being very new to Linux, I am having some difficulty. I know that my wireless card is an Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb), but I need to find the chipset. 
I tried following the instructions from another post on this site by typing

```
lspci -vv -s 02:00.0
```

which gave me the following information:

```
 2:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-N 7260
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 267
Region 0: Memory at 90600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

How do I find the chipset from this? In the other post, the chipset appeared on the first line next to the name of the card, but it didn't happen for me.

I also tried typing

```
lspci -nn -s 02:00.0
```

giving

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev bb)
```

I know 8086:08b1 is the manufacturer code and device ID in hexidecimal for the wireless card, but I do not know how to use this to find the chipset.
I Googled the code, but I did not find anything that was clearly useful.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you call "chipset"?

Comment: According to the Aircrack-ng tutorial, the chipset is the electronics on the card that allow it to function wirelessly. I need to "determine the chipset" before I install the program.

Comment: Some cards have marketing names like D-Link bla-bla-bla. The manual says that you need to determine the real chipset to find out if the card is supported. It your case the chipset is Intel 7260 as I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your wireless chipset is

```
Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev bb)
```

Comment: mine says "rev 59" but when I go to Intel's web site it only offers drivers for "Rev C" and "Rev D".  Does Ubuntu report revisions differently?

Comment: You don't need drivers from Intel site.

Comment: it wouldn't recognize the device as even existing...

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/dual-band-wireless-ac-7260-bluetooth-brief.pdf) there are 3 specific models, but it really [doesn't matter](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Intel_Dual_Band_Wireless-AC_7260_(7260HMW)) as they are [supported](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi#Supported_Devices) via the iwlwifi driver. You may need to install the [iwlwifi-firmware](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lucid&arch=i386&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=iwlwifi) for your ubuntu relaease if it's not already installed. Based on the information you have provided, it looks like it's properly installed and using the correct driver.